# How to change font for greek letters in R plot

Tags: r, plot, expression

How can I change the style of greek letters displayed on a plot in R?  For example, I am using expression() to annotate a plot with lowercase phi:

```
plot(1:10)
text(2,9, expression(phi["1,2"]), cex=2)
```

[image]

I would like the style of phi to match the style in a document (e.g., with MS Word "insert symbol" command), which looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `varphi` instead of `phi`

```
text(2,9, expression(varphi["1,2"]), cex=2)
```

[image]